# Undead form is still generating events

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

I have a form that the user can open from another form:

```
  private void btnEditTemplate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     using (frmReport EditReport = new frmReport()) 
     {
        EditReport.ShowDialog();
        EditReport.Close(); 
        EditReport.Dispose();
     }
  }
```

As you can see, I've called close, dispose, and even placed the form in a using block. The form has some controls bound to static BindingLists that are maintained outside the form, and changing those lists triggers events.

Despite everything, if the user later opens another copy of this form, I am finding that events for the original form are still being run, even though it is closed and disposed.

What to do I need to do to KILL this thing? Stakes through the heart?

**Update:** as was indicated in the comments, the problem was the static BindingList objects were maintaining databindings to the old form. For me the solution was to get rid of the BindingList objects as I wasn't making any (intentional) use of their databinding properties anyway.

Comment: Unsubscribe from events perhaps? Unset the bindings?

Comment: @MeirionHughes - I guess so, but my real question is, why doesn't disposing of the form do this?

Comment: Disposing is only for cleaning up _unmanaged_ resources that will never be cleaned up by the GC. It can be used for a general clean up, but its original use was for unmanaged cleanup. Finally, if you don't unsubscribe from an object event handler then the object is not orphaned and the GC cannot free it up; so it it will live on.

Comment: Because subscribing to events isn't controlled by the Garbage Collector. Besides if your using BindingList controls you don't explicitly have to subscribe to any events. The solution is to remove any explicit bindings you've added in the Form_closing event. I get your question though, like "why does unsubscribed events cause memory leaks?" To give you more control.

Comment: I think there's a clue here: 'static bindinglists'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the event handlers and data bindings at the moment, your code is little bit overkill at the moment. You could get away just this:

```
using (frmReport EditReport = new frmReport())
{
    EditReport.ShowDialog();
}
```

As you are showing it as a dialog by the time it got to your `.Close()` call the form was closed anyway. And the `using` statement calls `.Dispose()` for you.

Now, when you dispose a form you are basically removing the form from its parent, if you have one, disposing of all child controls, and freeing up the Windows handle.

However, it does not know how to detach your event handlers and it does not know how to remove data bindings. Since these things are references into your form the garbage collector will count the form as a live object and won't try to collect it.

So if you have any handlers within your form listening to external events and they fire then your form will try to handle them.

You need to make sure that when your form closes that you detach all handlers and unbind all data bindings.

Opening the form a second time has no direct relationship to the first, but it is likely that it caused your data source to start raising events or updating values and that's what tripped your original form.

Comment: My code is not "overkill", as overkill implies "kill", and the very reason I asked the question is that none of it was killing. I left everyting in to show what I had tried and failed with in my attempts to kill. As the source of the problem was the static BindingLists maintaining databindings to the old form, I've marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I find it good practice to write event subscription code to be tolerant of being called after you unsubscribe from the event.  This can happen in a variety of ways.

I don't know what experimentation you did, but for example, if you wrote this:

```
private void btnEditTemplate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (frmReport EditReport = new frmReport()) 
  {
    EditReport.ShowDialog();
    EditReport.Close(); 
    EditReport.Dispose();
  }
  using (frmReport EditReport2 = new frmReport()) 
  {
    EditReport2.ShowDialog();
    EditReport2.Close(); 
    EditReport2.Dispose();
  }
}
```

then there may still be events in the message queue for the first dialog that will not get processed until you enter the modal message loop in the ShowDialog() call on the second instance.

Even with the Dispose() you have, the Garbage Collector will not reclaim the first object, because of the references to it in these subscriptions in the message queue. If you write your event subscriptions to do nothing if the object they are delivered to is already disposed, then there will be no harm done.  what to check varies depending on what base class you are using.  Worst case, you implement your own IsDisposed or IsClosed instance variable.

Comment: It is necessary for your form to unsubscribe from all events to long-lived objects that are outside of your form.  If you do not, then those subscriptions will keep your object in memory as long as that outside object lives. I'm assuming that is not the issue you are dealing with.